# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed", I cant figure it out

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I've been trying to get this to work for a while and I've found plenty of examples to compare it too. Yet no matter what I try I get the same error. Can you guys please take a look at this and point me in the right direction.

thanks
here is the code/query:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS BigM_S2802312_WIP;

USE BigM_S2802312_WIP;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADDRESSTYPE (
    AddType_ID                  CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Add_Type                    VARCHAR(15)
)Engine=innodb;             


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (
    Cust_Number                 INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Cust_FName                  VARCHAR(30), 
    Cust_LName                  VARCHAR(30),
    Cust_Phone                  CHAR(10),
    Address_ID                  INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (Address_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS(Address_ID)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADDRESS (
    Address_ID                  INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Address_st                  VARCHAR(50),
    Address_City                VARCHAR(30), 
    Address_State               VARCHAR (3), 
    Address_Postcode            CHAR(4), 
    Add_TypeID                  CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Add_TypeID) REFERENCES ADDRESSTYPE (AddType_ID)
)Engine=innodb;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JOBTYPE (
    JobType_ID                  INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    JobType_Name                VARCHAR(30)
)Engine=innodb;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEPARTMENT (
    Dept_ID                     INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Dept_Name                   VARCHAR(40)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STORE (
    Str_Num                     INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Str_Name                    VARCHAR(50), 
    Str_Phone                   CHAR(10),
    Str_Fax                     CHAR(10),
    Str_Email                   VARCHAR(40), 
    StoreManagerID              INT NOT NULL,
    SupStore_Num                INT,
    Address_ID                  INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (StoreManagerID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Emp_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SupStore_Num) REFERENCES STORE (Str_Num),
    FOREIGN KEY (Address_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS (Address_ID)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STOREDEPARTMENT (
    StrDept_ID                  INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    StrDept_Phone               CHAR(10), 
    StrDept_Email               VARCHAR(40),
    DeptSupervisorID            INT NOT NULL,
    Str_Num                     INT NOT NULL,
    Dept_ID                     INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (DeptSupervisorID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Emp_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Str_Num) REFERENCES STORE (Str_Num),
    FOREIGN KEY (Dept_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (Dept_ID)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BRAND (
    Brand_ID                    INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Brand_Name                  VARCHAR(30)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE (
    Emp_ID                      INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Emp_FName                   VARCHAR(30), 
    Emp_LName                   VARCHAR(30), 
    Emp_Phone                   CHAR(10), 
    Emp_DoB                     DATE,
    Emp_StartDate               DATE,
    Emp_TaxFNum                 CHAR(12), 
    Emp_HourlySalary            DOUBLE(10,2),
    StrDept_ID                  INT NOT NULL,
    SupvisorID                  INT,
    Address_ID_Postal           INT NOT NULL,
    Address_ID_Resident         INT NOT NULL,
    Emp_JobTypeID               INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (StrDept_ID) REFERENCES STOREDEPARTMENT (StrDept_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SupvisorID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Emp_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Address_ID_Postal) REFERENCES ADDRESS (Address_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Address_ID_Resident) REFERENCES ADDRESS (Address_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Emp_JobTypeID) REFERENCES JOBTYPE (JobType_ID)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PAYSLIP (
    Pay_ID                      INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Pay_date                    DATE,
    Pay_num_of_hours            DOUBLE(4,2), 
    Pay_amount_gross            DOUBLE(6,2), 
    Emp_ID                      INT NOT NULL,
    Str_Num                     INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Emp_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Emp_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Str_Num) REFERENCES STORE (Str_Num)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT (
    Prod_Num                    INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Prod_Desc                   VARCHAR(50),
    Prod_Size                   VARCHAR(10), 
    Prod_Price                  DOUBLE(4,2),
    Prod_BrandID                INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Prod_BrandID) REFERENCES BRAND (Brand_ID)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INVENTORY (
    ProductNum                  INT NOT NULL,
    Str_Num                     INT NOT NULL,
    Inv_QntyOnHand              INT,
    Inv_QtyOrdered              INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductNum, Str_Num),
    FOREIGN KEY (ProductNum) REFERENCES PRODUCT (Prod_Num),
    FOREIGN KEY (Str_Num) REFERENCES STORE (Str_Num)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMERORDER (
    CustOrd_ID                  INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CustOrd_Date                DATE,
    Cust_Number                 INT NOT NULL,
    Str_Num                     INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Cust_Number) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (Cust_Number),
    FOREIGN KEY (Str_Num) REFERENCES STORE (Str_Num)
)Engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDERONLINE (
    CustOrd_ID                  INT NOT NULL,
    Prod_Num                    INT NOT NULL,
    OrdLn_DateArrived           DATE,
    OrdLn_DatePicked            DATE,
    OrdLn_Qnty                  INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (CustOrd_ID, Prod_Num),
    FOREIGN KEY (CustOrd_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERORDER (CustOrd_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Prod_Num) REFERENCES PRODUCT (Prod_Num)   
)Engine=innodb;
```

here are the errors im getting in phpmyadmin:

```
Error
SQL query:


CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
    Cust_Number                 INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Cust_FName                  VARCHAR(30), 
    Cust_LName                  VARCHAR(30),
    Cust_Phone                  CHAR(10),
    Address_ID                  INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (Address_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS(Address_ID)
)Engine=innodb
MySQL said: Documentation

#1005 - Can't create table `bigm_s2802312_wip`.`customer` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)
```

**InnoDB Status**

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2018-09-27 19:59:31 58c Error in foreign key constraint of table `bigm_s2802312_wip`.`customer`:
Create  table `bigm_s2802312_wip`.`customer` with foreign key constraint failed. Referenced table `bigm_s2802312_wip`.`address` not found in the data dictionary near 'FOREIGN KEY (Address_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS(Address_ID)
)Engine=innodb'.
```

**Edit**
I know I can get rid of the error by unticking the 'Enable foreign key checks' option, but I believe that option is required for my assignment.

Comment: Create all of your tables first then alter them to add the foreign key constraints.

Comment: Or just change the order: create `Address` before `Customer`

Comment: The script is executed line by line (more precisely, statement by statement, but it doesn't matter). So when `FOREIGN KEY (Address_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS(Address_ID)` line is executed the table ADDRESS is not created yet (the lines which creates it are posessed below). Simply reorder table creation statements.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I can't believe it was so simple.... I'm a little embarrassed lol.

Comment: Of course it is not so simple after all. You have cycles in your FKs, so you can't simply reorder the create table statements. You need to first create all the tables and then add all FKs (or create the table in some order and move only the cycle completing FKs to the end)

Comment: Ya, I ended up moving 3 (coulda been 4) FK's to the bottom. Just realising what the error was and being reminded what I was taught (have it written in large bold letters in my notes) that its run line by line helped a lot.